# Graph partitioning in 2 clusters minimizing between cluster edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, partitions

I've been looking for an algorithm which divides an undirected graph into 2 subgraphs.

However, unlike most existing work on graph partitioning out there (like METIS), I don't intend to obtain subgraphs that contain the same approximate number of vertices. Instead, I would like these 2 subgraphs to have similar count of edges.

Is there a name for this problem?

Comment: Would a partition of the line graph work for you? You would then obtain a set of vertices that, once removed, partition your graph into two similar sized sets of edges, right?